# Adjusting rails app to conform to convention regarding AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a model 'Player', and on loading the home page, it displays a picture of a random player. When clicked, it increases a field (num_clicks) on that player by 1.

Right now I have:

- jQuery that listens for a click event on the picture
- It makes an AJAX request to the server at static_pages_controller#player_clicked, sending the player's ID, which is stored in the DOM
- The controller updates the player's field, and sends the new values back (via JSON) to the AJAX request's success callback
- The success callback then uses jQuery to insert the new value into the DOM

All of the jQuery for this feature is in `/home.js.coffee`, is this the right place to put this?

Should I be using `link_to` within the picture instead of a click-listener on the picture?

The `home` page (on loading) displays @player.num_clicks, so it would be nice if this number would update automatically instead of having to overwrite it (in the AJAX success callback) with the new value provided by the server. Is this possible?

Right now, what I'm doing is basically working, but I'm fairly confident that it is not the 'rails way', and I'd like to address that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use link_to with picture and make this change.
The rails way would be use link_to with remote => true

```
<%=link_to ...., :remote => true%>
```

and on controller#action write a js erb template like app/views/static_pages/player_clicked.js.erb which will have all the javascript which you have written in success callback.

You'll have to get updated clicks count from server in any case you cannot avoid it.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks! How would I handle other aspects of the AJAX call (e.g. beforeSend, Error, AfterSuccess, etc.)

Comment: Isn't the poster in that thread suggesting using jQuery callbacks, which I'm already doing now? What's the benefit of switching to link_to if I'm going to need to do this with jQuery events anyway?